# Spring boot with high concurrency

Tags: spring, concurrency

We have a spring project with a huge of scheduled jobs.  We used @scheduler to perform each special job. But, we want all of the jobs were run in parallel. So in each job, we create a new Thread to perform every 20 tasks, and each task calls to the third-API to get data, process and save to the database. But when we deploy the app on the server, we have trouble with high CPU, it's higher than 100%. How can we solve this problem? Have any framework to manage and perform multiple concurrent scheduled tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Think about switching to reactive approach with [reactor](https://projectreactor.io/), it has a great and extremely simple mechanism for managing threads and scheduled tasks, on the other hand, this solution imposes some limitations and you may have to rewrite some parts of the system.

Also you can try [Quartz](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html)